# nilpotent group implies solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Can someone please do a simple proof of this:  If a group, G, is nilpotent then it is solvable.

I'm pretty bad at math and am just trying to figure this out.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Since the derived series is a subsequence of the descending central series, if the latter stabilizes then so does the former. That takes care of the problem rather trivially if those are the definitions you're using. What definitions are you using for nilpotent and solvable?

Comment: @seaturtles, "+1", please make it into an answer, it is a clean argument, which holds for arbitrary groups.

Answer (score 2):

Finite case, use induction on the order of $G$: take $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $P$ is normal, and, being a $p$-group, solvable. But $G/P$ is again nilpotent and hence solvable. Now both $P$ and $G/P$ are solvable and $G$ must be solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nifty alternative proof.  If $G$ is finite and nilpotent, it is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, i.e. we can write $$G=P_1\times P_2 \times \cdots P_n$$
with $P_i$ a Sylow $p_i$-subgroup of $G$, for each prime divisor $p_i$ of $|G|$.  Thus given any nonempty subset $\{i_1,\ldots , i_m\}$ of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ we have that $P_{i_1}\times \cdots \times P_{i_m}$ is a subgroup of $G$. It follows by the [converse to Hall's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup#A_converse_to_Hall.27s_theorem) that $G$ is solvable.

Comment: Though of course this argument is to some extend circular (since the proof of the converse of Hall's theorem uses that $p$-groups are solvable, and that would have ended the argument a step earlier).